Highcharts animation issue with scrollablePlotArea
I'm facing an animation issue with Highcharts when using scrollablePlotArea along with a filter dropdown. Here's the problem:
When I click the filter button to open the dropdown, the animation is not smooth.
However, when I close the filter dropdown, the animation works fine.
I suspect that the issue might be related to how I'm calculating the minHeight for the scrollablePlotArea, but I'm not sure.
Here's a simplified version of my React code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react18-mui-abgufj?file=App.tsx
I've already tried adjusting the minHeight value dynamically based on whether the dropdown is open or closed, but the issue persists.
Can anyone please help me identify what might be causing this animation problem and how I can fix it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I don't think that the problem here is related to scrollablePlotArea because when we delete this option the issue remains. From Highcharts side everything works fine so I guess this issue is more related to ReactJS.

@DominikChudy any suggest what changes i can make to have this fixed

Unfortunately, I don't have any ideas on how to fix this problem. Perhaps someone who's more into React can assist you.
